# Using Sessions To Remember User on PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, session

Intro: I'm trying to learn PHP on $_SESSION. What I was trying to do is call the value assigned through sessions that when you close your tab will keep the value assigned and echoes it on the browser when you open a tab in the browser.

Issue: There's something wrong with my code where for some reason I couldn't echo the value entered in on a form.

The form looks like this:

```
Name:_____________
Email:_____________ Remember me? __  SUBMIT
```

I made it so that $_SESSION['name'] = "John" and $_SESSION['email'] = "someemail@email.com" only when user click on "remember me".

If you close a "tab" on the browser but not the browser itself should echo...

```
John
someemail@email.com

Here's your download link (some link here)...
```

But of course if you close the browser, session is lost. Cookies can be used but I'm working on sessions to learn more.

Below's code runs but for some reason I couldn't echo values from $_SESSION variables.

```
<?php 

 //Start session
    session_start(); 
    // session
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {

$customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];
if (!($customer_name)) {
$customer_name = $_POST['name'];
}
$customer_email = $_SESSION['email'];
if (!($customer_email)) {
$customer_email = $_POST['email'];
}

    }


//If form submit validate
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // Santize fields here but FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING isn't necessary as there is no absolute way 
    //to validate names absolutely 
    // Also shows error message if there's error 
    if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
        $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid first name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your first name.<br/>';
    }

    // Sanitize and validate email
    // Error message shows if any
    if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors .= "$email is NOT a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
    }


    // If no errors, submitted form is emailed
    if (!$errors) {

        echo "I did something!<br /><br />"; // might add some message
        //downloadLink();
        echo "<br /><br />";



    }




    } else {
        echo '<div id="error">' . $errors . '<br /></div>';
    }



?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Name:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br />";
  }
else {
?> 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" size="25" /><br />
<?php } ?>

Email:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email']."<br /><br />";

    // echo link.. downloadLink();
  }
else {
?>  
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" size="25"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
<?php } ?>


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is that you are trying to solve! If you just want comments on your code, the place to go is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sessions are automatically deleted when a user closes a web browser, as opposed to a persistent cookie.

Comment: Remember me should be stored in cookies. not in session. and not in database, because they are not that important.

Comment: Why session ... I think local storage would be better option btw your code is vulnerable to **XSS**

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmm there must be a way... on w3schools.com you can <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
    else
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
    echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
    ?>  it spits out Views=1 (2, 3, 4 so on when you reopen browser)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя thanks but it's not implemented anywhere only an exercise to learn PHP.

Comment: If you close a tab yes, but not the browser itself in its entirety.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see got it. That was just my goal was that if you close the "tab" trying to spit out the value entered in $_SESSION['name'] and $_SESSION['email']

Comment: @mythoslife Put this at the beginning (under session_start();) `if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { echo "Your session is not good"; } else { echo "Session is set"; }` then replace `$customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];` with `$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['remember'];` and you will start getting results. Sorry, I couldn't spend too much time on this. Sessions are not my strong point.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Thank you I think that should work. Thanks.

Comment: @mythoslife You're welcome. If you wish, I can make it as an answer in order to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the beginning under `session_start();`

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { 
echo "Your session is not good"; 
} else { echo "Session is set"; 
}
```

then replace `$customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];` with `$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['remember'];` and you will start getting results.